# Accessing method from one class to another class in same package

Tags: java

I have two classes called AdminLogin and CreateCustomer in the same package 'testing. I written a method commonLogin() in AdminLogin.java for LOGIN purpose.So i need to call the commonLogin() in CreateCustomer class,instead of writing the same login code.How can i do this? Any one please tell me.
 AdminLogin.java:

```
 package testing;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

        public class AdminLogin {       

    public static void commonLogin()
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit BluBilling
        driver.get("http://testing.blubilling.in");
       //Fetching the username and password
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("j_username"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("xxxx");
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("j_password"));
        element1.sendKeys("zzzz");
        // Entering into bluBilling application
       element.submit();
      }


      public static void main(String[] args) {

        AdminLogin .commonLogin();
      }
   }
```

and CreateCustomer.java

```
  package testing;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class CreateCustomer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
    // not the implementation.
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // And now use this to visit BluBilling
    driver.get("http://testing.blubilling.in");
   //Fetching the username and password
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("j_username"));

    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("xxxx");
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("j_password"));
    element1.sendKeys("zzzz");
    // Entering into bluBilling application
    element.submit();
    //Creating a Customer
    driver.navigate().to("https://testing.blubilling.in/customer  /createCustomer2");
   //Entering the details of the Customer
   WebElement element4 = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
   element4.sendKeys("");
   WebElement element5 = driver.findElement(By.id("firstName"));
   element5.sendKeys("chris");
   WebElement element6 = driver.findElement(By.id("lastName"));
   element6.sendKeys("broad");
   WebElement element7 = driver.findElement(By.id("emailPrimary"));
   element7.sendKeys("chris@blusyn.com");
   WebElement element8 = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
   element8.sendKeys("");
   WebElement element9 = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
   element9.sendKeys("Chris1234");
   WebElement element10 = driver.findElement(By.id("confirm"));
   element10.sendKeys("Chris1234");
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   //Saving the Customer details
   WebElement element11 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Save']"));
   element11.click();
  }
  }
```

Comment: Create a `AdminLogin` object in `CreateCustomer` class. then call the `commonLogin` method

Comment: @Giri - `commonLogin` is a static method.

Comment: How can we create a object for a static method @Giri

Answer (score 0):

In *CreateCustomer*:

> AdminLogin.commonLogin();

is what you need.

But, I would recommend that *CreateCustomer* and *AdminLogin* be 2 separate functions in one single class, say *Admin*, since they are the actions that an admin could perform (if I understand your task right).
Goodluck.